# Local jquery datepicker implementation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to implement a local version of JQuery datepicker in a Web UI 
(I downloaded the scripts using NuGet),

I started off using an empty project from Visual Studios 2015,

I tried doing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. However when I use the links from the website it works perfectly fine

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

I'm quite new to using Web Forms,

Thanks in advance

Comment: where do you put the sources for the scripts?

Comment: I didn't include the directories for the scripts so it wasn't working but it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the links to the directories,

Thanks to @Mark's response,

I added ./ in the src for all of them and it worked

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
```